# Messenger Bot: how to get id, name and user's profile picture url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, messenger

I have Messenger Bot and want to do this action.

1. User click Button Template(URL) .
2. Messenger opens new  tab
3. On Web app header display header with **fullname, display Picture**

All these data are  public data ex: user fullname, picture url to display.
I know can use Graph API with USER_ID,

BUT In Messenger Bot can get only SCOPE_ID, so it cannot be used in graph api.

Any way to achieve like this
**and No login required.**

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to use the User Profile API, you can make a GET call to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<USER_ID>?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

`<USER_ID>` is the page-scoped ID `PSID` that returned with any messaging object

Comment: Is there any way to get the user's profile URL from a PSID?

Comment: I get Unsupported get request. Object with ID '<<the id returned>>' does not exist